# How to post process photos like Ildiko Neer did?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, reverse-engineering

I am shocked. I have seen [Ildiko Neer's photos](http://500px.com/ildiko-neer) (for example,  http://500px.com/photo/12062795). Could someone explain: what should I do, from beginning, to get so result.
Any valid direction :). Sorry for my question, but if you see these masterpieces, you will understand me.

**ADDED**

I have tried that receipt, [here is my result (sun light is REAL)](http://500px.com/photo/14148999). 
Of course, she has forgotten at least one filter

- Indian Summer.

Comment: I think you're labouring under the misapprehension that this is heavily post-processed when it is more likely just a shot where the photographer has waited for nice light.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall looks like both to me...

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I understand the first part of work (waiting for a good time and light). What next?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to a previous [image](http://500px.com/ildiko-neer/stories/52243/what-i-done-in-post-processing) that she posted she use a variety of post editing. 
She makes use of NIK COLOR Efex Pro

- Glamour Glow
- Brilliance

Then in Photoshop she adds more light with

- Knoll Light Factory
- Tiffen

It isn't exactly the same as in the image that you linked but should give a rough idea of her process.

Comment: thank you for answer. I will try and notice what I will get.

Comment: really heavy on post processing then... Even the sun and the light has been added.  The result is nice though.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a tone-mapped (HDR) image, with a beautifully lit scene to start with. You'll need to take a few differently exposed pictures (on a tripod, so they match up perfectly), and then add in your own artistic flare on top.

Comment: I'm not convinced that these are HDR images. They don't really have the look, I think. Looks a lot more like Photoshop filter work with lots of saturation.

Comment: Maybe, but the background leaves and the leaves that are blocking the sun look like they've been very slightly tonemapped to retain a hair of detail before being saturated to within an inch of their lives :)

Comment: Pretty hard to do multiple exposures of leaves and have them line up though...

Comment: Tripod, calm morning, fast bracket burst centered on 1/50th... not that hard. You may be right, it might just be one image with a lot of post. I think you could pull it off in many ways.

Comment: Check her previous image she has a "post process" which should give a rough idea of what she does (it does look different from the one OP references): "NIK COLOR Efex Pro, glamour glow, brillance" "Knoll Light Factory and with Tiffen" http://500px.com/ildiko-neer/stories/52243/what-i-done-in-post-processing

Comment: @fluf post your comment as an answer as it's the right one. Personally I can't stand whats done with these photos, it makes it look like bad seventies fantasy book covers sans the elves